# What is the value of this normal cdf?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

What is the value of this normal cdf?

$$ 1 - \Phi \left( \frac { \Phi ^ { - 1 } ( 0.99 ) } { \sqrt { 60 } } \right) $$

The answers says $ 0.62 $ but I get $ 1 - 0.62 $. What are the step by step calculations? How can I use a calculator to solve this?

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct.

$\Phi^{-1}[0.99]\approx{2.33}$ so

$1-\Phi(0.3)=\mathbb{P}[Z>0.3]$ cannot be $ >0.5$

To have a result $>0.5$ ,  $\Phi^{-1}[.]$ should be <0.